# Error in combining multiple csv files into one using matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I really need help regarding merging multiple CSV files into single file. At the first time, I managed to run this code :

```
%% Merge multiple CSV files into one CSV file
myDir = uigetdir                                                        % gets directory from any folder
d=dir(fullfile(myDir,'*.csv'));                                         % retrieve the files
fido=fopen(fullfile('finalCSVnew.csv'),'w');                            % open output file to write
for i=1:length(d)
  fidi=fopen(fullfile(myDir,d(i).name));                                % open input file
  fwrite(fido,fread(fidi,'*char'));                                     % copy to output
  fclose(fidi);                                                         % close that input file
end
fido=fclose(fido); clear fid* d                                         % close output file, remove temporaries
```

Turns out I have to change the command for "myDir" so it can select multiple file in one folder, not all file in one folder which need to be processed. So I change the code above to:

```
%% Merge multiple CSV files into one CSV file
myDir = uigetfile('*.csv','Select the data file','MultiSelect','on');   % gets directory from any folder
d=fullfile(myDir,'*.csv');                                              % retrieve the files
fido=fopen(fullfile('finalCSVnew.csv'),'w');                            % open output file to write
for i=1:length(d)
  fidi=fopen(fullfile(myDir,d(i).name));                                % open input file
  fwrite(fido,fread(fidi,'*char'));                                     % copy to output
  fclose(fidi);                                                         % close that input file
end
fido=fclose(fido); clear fid* d                                         % close output file, remove temporaries
```

and there is an error message

> Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your second code:

- if you select only one file, `uigetfile` returns its name in a `char` string, if you select more than one file, their names are returned in a `cellarray` therefore you have to manage it. You can use the function `class` to check it
- in the call to `fopen(fullfile('finalCSVnew.csv'),'w')` you do not provide the `path` in the call to `fullfile` therefore it seems useless
- you have also to manage the case in which you abort the selection of the file. In this case, the returned value of `uigetfile` is `0`

You can update your code in the following way

```
% Call uigetfile by specifying file name and path as output
[f_name,f_path] = uigetfile('*.txt','Select the data file','MultiSelect','on');   % gets directory from any folder
% Check for file selection abort
if(~strcmp(class(f_name),'double'))
      fido=fopen(fullfile(f_path,'finalCSVnew.txt'),'w'); % open output file to write
   % check for the number of selected files
   % if multiple file
   if(strcmp(class(f_name),'cell'))
      % Loop over the selected files
      for i=1:length(f_name)
         fidi=fopen(fullfile(f_path,f_name{i}));                                % open input file
         fwrite(fido,fread(fidi,'*char'));                                     % copy to output
         fclose(fidi);                                                         % close that input file
      end
   else
      fidi=fopen(fullfile(f_path,f_name));                                % open input file
      fwrite(fido,fread(fidi,'*char'));                                     % copy to output
      fclose(fidi);                                                         % close that input file
   end
   fido=fclose(fido); clear fid* d
else
   disp('File Selection Aborted')
end
```

**Alternative solution**

If you just want to merge some files, you can use the `system` function to call `DOS` command.

```
% Call uigetfile by specifying file name and path as output
[f_name,f_path] = uigetfile('*.txt','Select the data file','MultiSelect','on');   % gets directory from any folder
% Check for file selection abort
if(~strcmp(class(f_name),'double'))
   fido=fullfile(f_path,'finalCSVnew.txt'); % open output file to write
   % check for the number of selected files
   % if multiple file
   if(strcmp(class(f_name),'cell'))
      % Loop over the selected files
      for i=1:length(f_name)
         system(['type ' fullfile(f_path,f_name{i}) ' >> ' fido])
      end
   else
      system(['copy ' fullfile(f_path,f_name) ' ' fido])
   end
else
   disp('File Selection Aborted')
end
```

Comment: Hi @il_raffa I am sorry I want to ask you again. I actually have made a new thread but seems my question is irresolvable. I want to merge multiple xls file into one new xls file with the same worksheet. Do you know how to do it? I know it has something to do with readtable() or xlsread(), but I do not know how to form the code. Thank you and sorry to ask you a question again.